# Can't start ASP.NET Core web API Docker on a specified port

Tags: docker, asp.net-web-api, dockerfile, asp.net-core-1.1

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
  FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:1.0 AS build-env

  WORKDIR /app

  # copy csproj and restore as distinct layers

  COPY *.csproj ./

  RUN dotnet restore

  # copy everything else and build

  COPY . ./

  RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

  # build runtime image

  FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:1.0

  WORKDIR /app

  COPY --from=build-env /app/out .

  EXPOSE 58912

  ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "SgaApi.dll"]
```

I used this command to build: `docker build -f Dockerfile -t sga .`

Run: `docker run -e "ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:58912" -it --rm sga`

[Application starts successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfJSd.png)

I can't access it from the browser. When I run the application using "dotnet run" it works fine.

Answer (score 4):

You have exposed the port, but you haven't published it. You can either use -P to publish all exposed ports or -p and then specify port mapping. For example:

```
docker run -p 58912:58912 -e "ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:58912" -it --rm sga
```